# ie8 update inherited color of :before content based on parent elements' class

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element

My unending adoration and admiration to anyone who can help me resolve a font awesome problem in ie8.  Yes I know ie8 is no fun but I need to make it work because ...well because.

The problem is related to ie8's refusal to update :before pseudo elements if the content: is left unchanged.  This makes it rather hard to control font color when an elements' parent receives a css class update such as 'selected' via jquery or javascript.  What is an elegant way to force a repaint of the pseudo element :before content?

```
<style>
.items div {color:red;}
.items dig.selected {color:green;}
</style>

$('.toggle').on('click', function(){$('.items').toggleClass('selected');});

<div class="items">
<div class="selected">item 1<i class="icon-arrow-left"></div>
<div>item 2<i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></div>
<a id="toggle">Toggle</a>
</div>
```

I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue at hand:  http://jsfiddle.net/SLpAE/1/

Works in ie >= 9  and 7 oddly enough as well as ie8 compatibility mode (with different issues), also works in Chrome, safari and FF

Comment: Did you try `color:inherit` for the `:before` rule? In case that doesn't work I would also try creating a separate rule explicitly for `.selected i:before` with the desired color.

Comment: @inhan - I couldn't find anything more elegant that what you have suggested. I ended up having to create an ie8 only style sheet that redefines .selected i:before  It was acting flaky if I made the content identical but once i changed the content from "\x047" to "\x407 " for example.  Now it works but if I add icons or create a subset or want to add additional key classes such as .on or .off I have to worry about yet another css file.  I feel that the best solution for my scenario would be something that shims the browser rather than having to maintain additional styling.

Comment: To make sure I would use a `<span>` with `{display:block;float:[left|right]}` instead of a `(:):before` or `(:):after` selector. But seeing it's the `<i>` tag I suppose you're using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), so that might not be the easiest solution (although it's more rigid).

Comment: @inhan - I'm not using Bootstrap for this project, I was just trying to leave [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) as vanilla as possible.  But now that I am writing additional style sheets for ie8 I will probably take your advice, go back and use more traditional elements...